# Notification count showing when application is installed in iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, push-notification, react-native-ios

When application is installed for the first time I am seeing notification badge count as 1 by default. I am not able to find from where it is coming.

I tried many approaches provided over SO, but none of them worked for me.

Comment: you can set it 0 by manual

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your AppDelegate.m

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];
```

Comment: He is not using Objective C I guess taking into account that he tagged `react-native-ios`

Comment: But in react-native you can edit this file in 'ios' folder.

Comment: Didn't know that :)